# Expand one div to cover another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using jQuery to expand a div while hovering it so it covers the entire width of the page. It contains a large table and I'm required to build for a low resolution but in reality everyone has a higher so this is an accepted workaround. My problem is that the div "jumps" down below the other divs instead of covering them as I would like it to. Anyone know how this can be achieved?

I've created a jsfiddle of it so you get the main idea: http://jsfiddle.net/MRNxt/1/

Hover the grey box and make it expand to the right covering the #asd2 in the sidebar instead of below it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MRNxt/4/

The solution involves adding absolute positioning to the log div when expanding and taking it out when collapsing. Also included is a small fix to avoid flickering while animating.

Comment: This works great, but I changed the animating variable and used filter(':not(:animated)') instead: http://jsfiddle.net/MRNxt/9/

Answer (score 0):

Add this css:

```
#asd2{
 position:absolute;
 z-index:-1;        
}
#log{
    background:white;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/MRNxt/2/

Comment: Thanks, that works well, but only for #asd2, if #asd is multiple lines that makes if jump anyway. I need a solution that is dynamic because I do not know the contents of the boxes (and there are more boxes in the real system)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that using something like lightbox/thickbox isn't suitable?

Alternatively, you will need to play around with absolute positioning and z-index. I'd advise figuring out your ideal layout before working on the animation. Put it together in CSSEdit/Firebug/whatever so that your boxes are exactly where you want them to be and then it will be simple to add to the animation script.

Or just use an off-the-shelf lightbox.

Comment: The layout is already finished, the animation is not the important thing, it is that it's visible on top of other windows. I use fancybox for some stuff, but this is required to be visible at all times without clicking anywhere.

Comment: No, what I mean is to build the secondary layout - the one where everything is enlarged. That way you'll know what css you need to transition to. Once you've done that, everything will be simple.

Comment: Ah ok I get it, yes, that is probably the best way to do it, but this was the only thing needed to be done, so now It's complete. If it wasn't supposed to be an internal tool then yes, that would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

This won't be the perfect answer:

http://jsfiddle.net/MRNxt/7/

but here I used a subContainer to allow you to have a 100% width and some border.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work any better than my original solution.